# storing csv files on a dedicated server

Tags: node.js, csv, heroku

I'm having trouble storing csv files on a heroku server. I have a javascript application running express and a few other node packages and wondering what I should do in order to maintain those csv files. Heroku will always wipe new data and revert to the last deployed code (https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted), so any new files added while the app is running will be erased. Wondering if I should look for another dedicated service to deploy the project on or store the data in a database.